# iOS drag objects with inertia

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am starting with gestures in iOS and I don't know how add inertia to my movements. Exactly in pan gestures.

In that moment I can move objects with this type of recognizer but I want a little system of physic similar to the effect of the scrolls view.

Someone can help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Take a look at Core Animation transitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, you have `translationInView:` and `velocityInView:`. velocity is the speed at which the user is moving their finger, in pixels/second. You can use the velocity to do find out the inertia the user "gives" the view when their finger is liften (the recognizer's state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`).

Comment: When I doing the inertia animation, can I also interfere the other properties during the animation. For example, the map inertially moves along the panning direction, during the animation, I want to change another property base on the immediate panning offset. Can I do that?

Comment: This is not a full answer, how would the equation be like to make that effect :(